# How do I loop through a tuple of lists element-wise?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a function that returns a tuple of two lists

```
def two_lists():
    return [1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I want to loop through the tuple in a manner similar to this

```
for v1, v2 in two_lists():
   print v1, v2

output:
    1, a
    2, b
    3, c
```

The only way I have found I find rather cumbersome!

```
a, b = two_lists()
for i, y in zip(a, b):
    print i, y
```

Is there a prettier more pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: If you want to make it terser, you can just do `for i, y in zip(*two_lists())`, which will upack the tuple in-place. Otherwise, if you're trying to say `zip` is un-pythonic, I would disagree.

Comment: Edited to add Python 2 tag.

Comment: Please, please, please do not use list comprehensions for their side effects. It's incredibly bad practice and inefficient. There is never a time when that is the correct solution.

Comment: So, having a resulting list with `[None, None, None, None]` is OK? That doesn't seem like the best advice here. I would advise against using that list comp solution.

Comment: Another nice python 3 way of doing it (Python 3.5 or higher only), which should satisfy all the above complaints: `print( *((i,y) for i,y in zip(*twolists()), sep = '\n')`

Comment: @MorganThrapp I was happy to see multiple unpacking functionality added to 3.5 precisely because of this complaint. There *should* have been a nice way to do a print-type operation in one line, but there wasn't. Now, there is.

Comment: hmm @RickTeachey You have unbalanced parentheses and the output seems to be -> `(1, 'a')\n(2, 'b')\n(3, 'c')`

Comment: @idjaw Whoops! Here it is corrected: `print( *((i,y) for i,y in zip(*twolists())), sep = '\n')`. That's equivalent to the required output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you can directly unpack `two_lists()` in your zip call.

```
for i, y in zip(*two_lists()):
    print i, y
```

This is the idiomatic way to do this.